# r cairo_pdf dotted line distorted

Tags: r, ggplot2, pdf-generation, cairo

I am trying to save a `ggplot2` plot using the `cairo_pdf()` function, but the markers of the dotted `geom_line()` keep getting stretched. Please see sample code and output below.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 0:10, y = 0:10)

p <- ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(aes(x, y), linetype = 3, size = 2, lineend = "round")

ggsave("ggsave.pdf", width = 7, height = 5)

pdf("pdf.pdf", width = 7, height = 5)
  print(p)
dev.off()

cairo_pdf("cairo_pdf.pdf", width = 7, height = 5)
  print(p)
dev.off()
```

Output using `ggsave()` with markers nice and round:
[image]

Output using `pdf()` same as `ggsave()`.

Output using `cairo_pdf()` with markers stretched and spacing between markers wrong:

[image]

Is there any way to make the `cairo_pdf()` output, specifically the `geom_line()`, look like the the other PDFs? I would like to use `cairo_pdf()` since it has some other benefits that really help with my work. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have the same problem using R base graphics. For instance:

```
pdf("r_base_pdf.pdf")
plot(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1), type = "l", lty = "11", lwd = 5)
dev.off()

cairo_pdf("r_base_cairo.pdf")
plot(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1), type = "l", lty = "11", lwd = 5)
dev.off()
```